# Waiting for Ajax Call before Setting Initial State in React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

I'm using react and redux and was wondering if the following was possible:

I'm making an "Edit Form" component and I want to set the initial state of `preselected` to this.props.user.preselected.id.

I can call `this.props.user.preselected.id` anywhere except for the case of setting the initial value.I keep getting a null value and I believe it's because the reducer `this.props.user` appears only after `this.props.fetchSingleUser` is complete.

Is it possible to set the initial state to a reducer that's currently being fetched within the same component?

```
class PropertyEdit extends Component {

  static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
  };

  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            preselected= this.props.user.preselected.id
        };       
  }


  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchSingleUser(this.props.params.id);
  }

....


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { 
    user:state.user.single
  };
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { 
    user:state.users.single
  };
}
```

action.js

```
export function fetchSingleUser(id) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.get(`${URL}/users/${id}`)
    .then(response => {
      dispatch({
        type:FETCH_USER,
        payload: response
      });
    })
   .catch(() => {
      console.log("Error ");
    });
  }
}
```

reducer:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = { single: null };

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_USER:
        return {...state, single: action.payload.data};
  }
  return state;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Verry common approach is to have 3 actions for an async operation

**types.js**

```
export const FETCH_USER_REQUEST = 'FETCH_USER_REQUEST'
export const FETCH_USER_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_USER_SUCCESS'
export const FETCH_USER_FAIL = 'FETCH_USER_FAIL'
```

**reducer.js**

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import * as types from './types';

const isFetching = (state = false, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.FETCH_USER_REQUEST:
      return true;
    case types.FETCH_USER_SUCCESS:
    case types.FETCH_USER_FAIL:
      return false;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const data = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.FETCH_USER_SUCCESS:
      return action.payload.data;
  }
  return state;
};

export default combineReducers({
  isFetching,
  data
});
```

So you can get `isFetching` prop in your component and show/hide your form

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think you should only render the form once you received the user data ?

- with redux thunk you could emit an action `USER_LOADED` once the fetch is done.
- this new action would update the redux store with `userLoaded = true`
- then you could pass `user.loaded` in your react component to display the form

Comment: I just added in my action creator. I think it makes sense. Are you saying that I should dispatch another action after I fetch the user and set that as my reducer to display in the component?

Comment: thanks. it seems that you already use redux thunk. it's perfectly normal  is that `this.props.user` is `null`, i'll edit my post to explain that